# PHP Ajax post datatables

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, datatables

I am trying to populate a datatable (datatables.net). I have a field which triggers a ajax post request after a change.

This is the JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if(window.location.href.indexOf("neuen-trade-anlegen") > -1) {
        var gf_id = 13;     
    }else if(window.location.href.indexOf("trade-bearbeiten") > -1) {
        var gf_id = 11;
    }else{
        return;
    }

    //Icon zu Label hinzufügen
    jQuery("label[for='" + jQuery("#input_" + gf_id + "_8").attr('id') + "']").html('Name <i class="fas fa-search" id="suchen"></i>');
    jQuery("label[for='" + jQuery("#input_" + gf_id + "_31").attr('id') + "']").html('Symbol <i class="fas fa-search" id="suchen2"></i>');
    
    //modal zu seite zur klasse modalanker hinzufügen
        //data-backdrop = false ist wichtig damit kein graues overlay!
        //z-index damit modal über seitenmenü ist
    var htmlmodal = '<div class="modal fade" id="suchen_modal" data-backdrop="false" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="z-index:2000">'+
                        '<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">'+
                            '<div class="modal-content">'+
                                '<div class="modal-header">'+
                                    '<h4>Nach Wert suchen</h4>'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">'+
                                        '<i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-times"></i>'+
                                    '</button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div class="modal-body">'+
                                    '<div class="container-fluid">'+
                                        '<div class="row">'+    //zeile1
                                            '<div class="col-9">'+  //col1                                              
                                                '<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">'+
                                                    '<div class="input-group-prepend">'+
                                                        '<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm"><i class="fas fa-search" id="suchen"></i></span>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                    '<input type="text" id="input_symbol" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="row">'+    //zeile2
                                            '<div class="col-12">'+ //col1
                                                '<table id="symbol_search_table" class="display" style="width:100%">'+
                                                    '<thead>'+
                                                        '<tr>'+
                                                            '<th>Symbol</th>'+
                                                            '<th>Name</th>'+
                                                            '<th>Type</th>'+
                                                            '<th>Region</th>'+
                                                            '<th>Währung</th>'+
                                                            '<th>Match</th>'+
                                                        '</tr>'+
                                                    '</thead>'+
                                                '</table>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="row">'+    //zeile3
                                            '<div class="col">'+    //col1
                                                '1 of 3'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                            '<div class="col">'+    //col2
                                                '2 of 3'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                            '<div class="col">'+    //col3
                                                '3 of 3'+
                                            '</div>'+                                       
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="row">'+    //zeile4                                    
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-light-primary font-weight-bold" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bold">Übernehmen</button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
    
    //modalanker muss element mit klasse modalanker auf seite sein
    // Inserting the code block to wrapper element
    //document.getElementById("modalanker").innerHTML = htmlmodal;
    jQuery( ".modalanker" ).append( htmlmodal );        
    
    //bootstrap modal bei klick auf suchen icon öffnen  
    jQuery('#suchen, #suchen2').on('click', function(){
        //alert("test");
        jQuery('#suchen_modal').modal('show');
        //jQuery('#suchen_modal').modal('show'); 
    })
    
    //symbol eingeben
    jQuery('#input_symbol').on('change', function(){
        var symbol = jQuery('#input_symbol').val();
            
        //datatable laden           
        jQuery('#symbol_search_table').DataTable({  
            "dataSrc": 'data',
            "ajax": {
                async: 'false',
                type: 'post',
                url: '../custom_scripts/alphavantage_api_symbol_search.php',
                data: {
                    symbol:symbol       
                }   
            },              
            "columns": [
                { title: 'Symbol', data: 'symbol' },
                { title: 'Name', data: 'name' },
                { title: 'Type', data: 'type' },
                { title: 'Region', data: 'region' },
                { title: 'Währung', data: 'currency' },
                { title: 'match', data: 'matchScore' }
            ]
        });             
    })  
})
```

Now in php, i am getting some data from alphavantage api which gives me an array which looks like this:
Update: The new json looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"symbol":"WST","name":"West Pharmaceutical Services Inc.","type":"Equity","region":"United States","currency":"USD","matchScore":"1.0000"},{"symbol":"WSTL","name":"Westell Technologies Inc.","type":"Equity","region":"United States","currency":"USD","matchScore":"0.8571"},{"symbol":"WSTG","name":"Wayside Technology Group Inc.","type":"Equity","region":"United States","currency":"USD","matchScore":"0.8571"},{"symbol":"WSTAX","name":"Ivy Science And Technology Fund Class A","type":"Mutual Fund","region":"United States","currency":"USD","matchScore":"0.7500"},{"symbol":"WSTYX","name":"Ivy Science And Technology Fund Class Y","type":"Mutual Fund","region":"United States","currency":"USD","matchScore":"0.7500"},{"symbol":"WSTRF","name":"Western Uranium & Vanadium Corp.","type":"Equity","region":"United States","currency":"USD","matchScore":"0.7500"},{"symbol":"WSTCX","name":"Ivy Science And Technology Fund Class C","type":"Mutual Fund","region":"United States","currency":"USD","matchScore":"0.7500"},{"symbol":"WAMIX","name":"WSTCM Credit Select Risk - Managed Fund Institutional Shares","type":"Mutual Fund","region":"United States","currency":"USD","matchScore":"0.7500"},{"symbol":"WSTBX","name":"Ivy Science And Technology Fund Class B","type":"Mutual Fund","region":"United States","currency":"USD","matchScore":"0.2500"}]}
```

And this is the php code:

```
//SYMBOL_SEARCH
$feed_url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=$symbol&apikey=$apikey";
$response = wp_remote_get( $feed_url );

$json = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
//echo ($json);
//json decodieren
$response = json_decode( $json, true );
$myarray = json_decode( $json, true );
//echo json_encode($response);

//remove bestmatches outer array
$myarray = $response['bestMatches'];
//echo json_encode($myarray);

//remove dots
$myarray = array_map(function($tag) {
    return array(
        'symbol' => $tag['1. symbol'],
        'name' => $tag['2. name'],
        'type' => $tag['3. type'],
        'region' => $tag['4. region'],
        'currency' => $tag['8. currency'],
        'matchScore' => $tag['9. matchScore']
    ); }, $myarray);
//echo json_encode($myarray);

//put in an array named data
$data_array = array("data" => $myarray);
echo json_encode($data_array);
```

The datatables just shows "processing" and is not populated at all. I guess something is wrong with the formatting of the array right? Or do you have any other suggestions? Any help would be really appreciated, because if have no idea how to continue with this problem.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything in your `success` function...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in the question I can see 3 problems - but there may be additional items hiding behind these 3 things:

**1. Naming the data source**

In your JSON, you have this at the start:

```
{"data:":[{"1. symbol":"WST","2. name"...
```

Specifically, the name of the array is `data:`. Note the colon which is *part of the name*.

By default, dataTables expects the array to be named `data` not `data:`.

So, you can either remove that extra colon from the source JSON, or you can define `data:` as the data source name in your `ajax` section:

```
dataSrc: 'data:'
```

I would recommend just removing the colon.

**2. Name/Value Pairs in the JSON**

A typical object in your JSON is this:

```
{
  "1. symbol":"WST",
  "2. name":"West Pharmaceutical Services Inc.",
  "3. type":"Equity",
  ...
  "9. matchScore":"1.0000"
}
```

Notice how each name includes a dot - for example, the `.` in `"1. symbol"`. In DataTables, this dot is interpreted as a navigator, for descending into [nested JSON](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html).

The solution is to remove these dots from the names in your source JSON.

I would recommend using `"symbol"` instead of `"1. symbol"`.

If you want to display "1. symbol" as an actual heading in your table, you can hard code that into the HTML, or use the DataTables `columns` option - for example:

```
columns: [
  { title: '1. Symbol',
    data: 'symbol' },
  { title: '2. Name',
    data: 'name' },
  { title: '3. Type',
    data: 'type' }
]
```

**3. Server-Side Processing**

The above 2 fixes should allow you to see your data. But you will still see unexpected items such as the following:

```
Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)
```

This is because when you are using `serverSide: true`, you need to provide some additional fields in the JSON sent from the server to DataTables.

You can [see an example here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). Specifically, look at the "returned data" section.

For example, because you have chosen to use `serverSide: true`, the server needs to tell DataTables how many total records there are, and how many filtered records. The server also needs to handle all sorting and filtering.

Also look at the "sent parameters" section, so you understand what information is sent from DataTables to the server. This is how DataTables tells the server what sorting/filtering/paging values the user has clicked on or entered.

I would recommend starting with `serverSide: false` - and get that working correctly first, before enhancing the table to use `serverSide: true`.

Comment: This explains a lot. I will try that out asap. Thanks so much for the detailed answer!

Comment: So i fixed the problems you mentioned above (see updated post). Sadly still no data is loaded. Any ideas what is wrong? The datatable just shows "loading..."  Console says  Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

Comment: i now also added the whole .js code, i am loading the table in a jquery ready function, not sure if this causes problems. When i hard coded the data, the table was displayed correctly...

Comment: My suggestion is to start with an empty page, and add in only the datatable (your "datatable laden" section). Get that working first. Then start adding extra functionality one step at a time.